# Is there a system-assigned variable to a "while .. read" loop in a bash script for the whole line?

Tags: bash, split

I am using the following script template to process a tab-separated text file:

```
  while IFS=$'\t' read -r column1 column2 column3 ; do
  printf "%b\n" "column1<${column1}>"
  printf "%b\n" "column2<${column2}>"
  printf "%b\n" "column3<${column3}>"
done < "myfile"
```

Can I still access the entire line via some internal variable?

Purpose: The text files are file indexes of external drives created in another script with

```
find "$1" \( -size +40k -fprintf ~/Documents/fs/${1}.txt '%CY-%Cm-%Cd-%CH-%CM \t %-10s \t %h \t %f\n' \)
```

I want to split the lines into separate files according to the file types (video, audio, pictures, archives, other).

Of course I can reassemble the original line by using all of the field variables, but is there a more direct way? Currently my script goes sth like this:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r fdate fsize ffolder filename ; do
f_ext=${filename##*.}
f_ext=${f_ext,,}

if  [[ "$f_ext" == "jpg" || "$f_ext" == "jpeg" ||  "$f_ext" == "gif" || "$f_ext" == "png" || "$f_ext" == "bmp" || "$f_ext" == "cbr" || "$f_ext" == "psd" || "$f_ext" == "jp2" || "$f_ext" == "tif"  || "$f_ext" == "tiff" ]];then
echo -e "$fdate\t$fsize\t$ffolder\t$filename" >> "$fdir/${txtfnpure}Pics.txt"

elif  [[ "$f_ext" == "mka" || "$f_ext" == "m4a" ||  "$f_ext" == "aac" || "$f_ext" == "mp3" || "$f_ext" == "ogg" || "$f_ext" == "mp2" || "$f_ext" == "wav"  || "$f_ext" == "wave" || "$f_ext" == "ac3"  || "$f_ext" == "wma" || "$f_ext" == "flac" || "$f_ext" == "fla" || "$f_ext" == "aiff"  || "$f_ext" == "aif" ]];then

    ...
```

Comment: No, but with bash you can simply read the entire line and split it on whitespace storing the individual fields as array elements with `while IFS=$'\t' read -r line; do arr=($line); # do stuff with fields; done` which will split the fields in `'\t'` into the elements of `arr`. See also `maptile -t` (equivalent to `readarray -t`) in `man bash` to automatically split the file into array elements. That way you have the whole line in `line` and the elements in `arr`.

Comment: @David This would split only on tabs, not on spaces in filenames?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Workaround with `bash`:

```
while IFS='' read -r line; do
  IFS=$'\t' read -r column1 column2 column3 <<< "$line"
  echo "complete line: $line"
  printf "%b\n" "column1<${column1}>"
  printf "%b\n" "column2<${column2}>"
  printf "%b\n" "column3<${column3}>"
done < "myfile"
```

Comment: Is `IFS=''` necessary ?

Comment: @Philippe: Yes. Without bash removes leading and trailing tabs/spaces and removes tabs/spaes that occur more than once.

Comment: bash does remove leading and trailing tabs/spaces, but after that, does not remove tabs/spaes that occur more than once. So you are right, it is necessary.